# cannot connect wireless to openwrt

Tags: wireless-router, lan, openwrt

I am using a modem at bridge mode and WDR3600 as openwrt router.
.I have a cable from modems LAN to WDRs WAN and a cable from WDR to pc.
I have connection via cable.
From 192.168.1.1 when I select to enable wireless ,it highlightes the `Generic MAC80211 802.11bgn (radio0)`  but I have no connection (signal is 0% and bitrate nothing).
(I am not sure what to do with radio1 device though)

/etc/config/wireless

```
config wifi-device 'radio0'
    option type 'mac80211'
    option channel '6'
    option macaddr '...'
    option hwmode '11ng'
    option htmode 'HT20'
    list ht_capab 'LDPC'
    list ht_capab 'SHORT-GI-20'
    list ht_capab 'SHORT-GI-40'
    list ht_capab 'TX-STBC'
    list ht_capab 'RX-STBC1'
    list ht_capab 'DSSS_CCK-40'

config wifi-iface
    option device 'radio0'
    option network 'wan2'
    option mode 'ap'
    option ssid 'myOpenWrt'
    option encryption 'psk2'
    option key 'mykey'

config wifi-device 'radio1'
    option type 'mac80211'
    option channel '36'
    option macaddr '...'
    option hwmode '11na'
    option htmode 'HT20'
    list ht_capab 'LDPC'
    list ht_capab 'SHORT-GI-20'
    list ht_capab 'SHORT-GI-40'
    list ht_capab 'TX-STBC'
    list ht_capab 'RX-STBC1'
    list ht_capab 'DSSS_CCK-40'
    option disabled '1'

config wifi-iface
    option device 'radio1'
    option network 'lan'
    option mode 'ap'
    option ssid 'OpenWrt'
    option encryption 'none'
```

(I am not sure what mode to select also,'ap' or 'sta' )?

/etc/config/network

```
config interface 'loopback'
    option ifname 'lo'
    option proto 'static'
    option ipaddr '127.0.0.1'
    option netmask '255.0.0.0'

config interface 'lan'
    option type 'bridge'
    option proto 'static'
    option ipaddr '192.168.1.1'
    option netmask '255.255.255.0'
    option _orig_ifname 'eth0.1 radio0.network1 radio1.network1'
    option _orig_bridge 'true'
    option ifname 'eth0.1 tap0'

config interface 'wan'
    option _orig_ifname 'eth0.2'
    option _orig_bridge 'false'
    option proto 'pppoe'
    option username '...'
    option password '...'
    option ifname 'eth0.1'

config interface 'wan2'
    option _orig_ifname 'eth0.2'
    option _orig_bridge 'false'
    option proto 'pppoe'
    option username '...'
    option password '...'
    option ifname 'eth0.2'

config switch
    option name 'eth0'
    option reset '1'
    option enable_vlan '1'

config switch_vlan
    option device 'eth0'
    option vlan '1'
    option ports '0t 2 3 4 5'

config switch_vlan
    option device 'eth0'
    option vlan '2'
    option ports '0t 1'
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok! I had to check 'lan' network from wireless (rasdio0) settings and it works!